# System.IO.IOException: The file exists When Moving File

Tags: c#

I've recently taken over some code from a colleague that has left the company. I plan to rewrite the code from scratch, but in the meantime I'm wondering about the following crash the program had when running automatically overnight:

```
System.IO.IOException: The file exists.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
at System.IO.FileInfo.MoveTo(String destFileName)
at Rexel_XML_Generator.Program.ProcessFiles(List`1 pdfFiles, List`1 files, CsvForXml csv, Dictionary`2 csvDictionary)
at Rexel_XML_Generator.Program.Main()
```

Obviously the program seems to have crashed because the file seems to already exist, but i dont see how it can do.

I've read about this error when windows exceeds the amount of temporary files it can have, but i dont think any temp files are being created. I've narrowed it down and found the code where the crash is.

The folder it is moving to is a dated folder for each run, so i dont think it was already there.

```
foreach (var pdFfile in pdfFiles)
        {
            var filename = pdFfile;

            // Copy to processing folder
            filename.CopyTo(ProcessingFolder + filename, true);

            //Copy to the Aroura server
            if (!Testing)
            {
                filename.CopyTo(@"\\89.1.1.233\AURINPUT\PDF_Archive\" + filename, true);
            }

            //Move to processed

            filename.MoveTo(TodaysFolder + @"\Data Processed\" + filename);
        }
```

If there was an error with this code, i'd expect it to crash most days? But this is the first occurrence of such a crash to my knowledge. Does anyone see how this crash could come to be?

---

Update 10/09/19

This hasn't reoccured which makes me think the issue lies outside of the code?
I've done a bit more digging and found this log file

```
[2019-08-21 04:17:52] system crashed error is System.IO.IOException: The file exists.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
at System.IO.FileInfo.MoveTo(String destFileName)
at Rexel_XML_Generator.Program.ProcessFiles(List`1 pdfFiles, List`1 files, CsvForXml csv, Dictionary`2 csvDictionary)
at Rexel_XML_Generator.Program.Main()
```

Which seems to be the same error as above from the event viewer

the ENTIRE program is in a try catch loop, and when it finds an error it does this:

```
 LogDataToFile.LogData($"system crashed error is {e}");
 LogDataToFile.CloseConnection();
```

which does

```
 public static void LogData(string message)
    {
        _writer.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] " + message);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public static void CloseConnection()
    {
        _writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You need to figure out for which file the program crashes and check in the destination location to see if the file really exist or not. If the code was running fine for all this time and now only crashing then its not the code issue.

Comment: Hi, i found the file in question yesterday when it crashed. The program creates the directory its moving the file to every time it runs, with a date and time stamp, so the directory was not there before the system ran, and it grabs the files its moving from one folder, so it cant have been in the original folder twice due to the name being the same. I'm at a loss :-(

Comment: Perhaps the application ran twice at the same time?

Comment: Agree with CodeCaster, likely the process which moves the file has been called twice in parallel. Where this code lives and how it gets called?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. The code runs via a scheduled task once per day, the task was not still running from the day before

Comment: From your log file - Issue is happening during `file.MoveTo`- Seems like same file (name) is available in Processed (`Data Processed`) folder